# How can I show model object through Forms to template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

There is a complex structure in my models and I don't know how I can link a Foreign Key to a Many to Many field on the same template.

It be easier to explain once the **models.py** is seen :

```
class Font(models.Model):
    font_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Background(models.Model):
    bk_color = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    ...


class FormOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    background = models.ForeignKey(Background, blank=True, null=True)
    checkbox = models.ManyToManyField(Font, blank=True)
    ...
```

I would like to do the following for each `Font Item` add a background color (`bk_color`) from the Foreign Key. Here comes the tricky part, this should be done on a Form. The user **cannot** choose his background, it's defined by the admin only through a Radio Select.

so I would like it the Form to show me something like this for the background color on each item.

Title : ____________

Checkbox :

[ X ] font_name1 - #333333 <-- Color Set by the admin on the administration panel

[ _ ] font_name2 - #94D32F

[ X ] font_name3 - #ffffff

The problem is that if I show the colors by the views I cannot give each checkbox item his own specific color.

How can I achieve the following ?

**forms.py :**

```
class CustomChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<p class="checkbox-choice" style="%s">%s</p>' % (obj.font_family, obj.font_name))


class FormOneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    checkbox = CustomChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Font.objects.all())
    background = forms.ModelChoiceFied(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=Background.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = FormOne
        fields = ['name']
```

**template file :**

```
<form action="{% url 'multistepform.views.step1' %}" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
{% csrf_token %}
...

<div class="checkbox-choice" style="background: ! BACKGROUND COLOR HERE ! ;">
{% for fcheck in form.background %}
    <div class="checkbox_id col-lg-3">{{ fcheck }}</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>

<input id="step1" type="submit" value="Submit" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```